# Translate a native JS to Angularjs to calculate days between two dates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble trying to convert or translate a native js script to calculate number of days between two dates from two scopes ('work_start' and 'work_end') but did not have any success.

Here is the code, actually it works, but an alert is fired in the console.log and I am not achieving to solve this.

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['work_start', 'work_end'], function() {
var date1 = $scope.work_start;
var date2 = $scope.work_end;

// First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
date1 = date1.split('-');
date2 = date2.split('-');

// Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

// We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

// This is the calculated difference in seconds
var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

// in Hours
var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

// and finaly, in days :)
var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24;

// alert(timeDifferenceInDays);
$scope.total_days = timeDifferenceInDays;
```

});

And this is the alert I am receiving:

```
angular.js:13283 TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
at app.js:3997
at c (angular.js:16419)
at m.$eval (angular.js:16884)
at m.$digest (angular.js:16700)
at m.$apply (angular.js:16992)
at g (angular.js:11313)
at y (angular.js:11511)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:11452)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13283(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9996m.$digest @ angular.js:16702m.$apply @ angular.js:16992g @ angular.js:11313y @ angular.js:11511t.onload @ angular.js:11452
```

I changed some things but this is the far I can get. Any help will be welcome

Comment: Looks like `work_start` or `work_end` are not always set. You can add a simple condition `if (!work_start || !work_end) { total_days=null; return; }` and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry @Claies, this error is due to a console.log from an other block, the value is not yet defined, thats why it gets undifined. But this has nothing to do with code pasted above (days between two dates)

Comment: Also notice that your callback can have form `function(newValues, oldValues, scope)` so instead of reading values from scope you can readthem from `newValues` e.g. `work_start = newValues[0]; work_end = newValues[1]` (I mean just add parameter `newValue` to your function)

Comment: This code will work fine if the values of `$scope.work_start` and `$scope.work_end` are dates formatted as strings in the format "MM-dd-yyyy". That error seems pretty self-explanatory; one of those scope properties is `null`. So, what's the question here?

Comment: I solved this considering the empty values, giving them a value of 0 if they didn't exist. This is a temporal fix, I will be working on this as @Travis suggest, to make a more compact code, with the proper angular markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Cannot read property 'split' of null
> ```

This means you're trying to use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function on something that is not a String. So where are you using the split function?

```
date1 = date1.split('-');
date2 = date2.split('-');
```

So where are date1/2 defined?

```
var date1 = $scope.work_start;
var date2 = $scope.work_end;
```

So where are `$scope.work_start`/`end` defined? Not sure, but probably in html. To simply fix this issue, do something like this:

```
if(date1 === null || date2 === null){
  alert("no dates given")
} else {
  date1 = date1.split('-');
  date2 = date2.split('-');
  ... // rest of your code
}
```

---

*Updating this section based on the discussion below...*

[Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can be a pain in JS. A newly initialized date object is simply the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 (UTC). If you're going to play with dates and times, look into a js library that makes Dates easier to work with like [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) or [Sugar](https://sugarjs.com/dates/).

[$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) watches those two dates and runs the 'days between' functionality if either changes. This is fine, however you must compensate for a range of issues, such as

> *the user changes `work_start` before `work_end`, and `work_start` is after `work_end`*
>
> *the user enters a date that is not in the correct format*

and a bunch of other stuff that can come up. You might want to think about incorporating a button to allow the user to update the dates after they're finished editing both. This will also allow your form to error-check the input, and not allow a submission if it's not in the correct format.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="workCont">
  <input ng-model="$scope.work_start"></input>
  <input ng-model="$scope.work_end"></input>
  <button ng-click="$scope.getDaysBetween()">Get Days Between</button>
  <p>Days Between: {{$scope.daysBetween}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var workApp = angular.module('workApp', []);

workApp.controller('workCont', function workCont($scope) {
  $scope.work_start = new Date();
  $scope.work_end = new Date();
  $scope.daysBetween = 0;
  $scope.getDaysBetween = function(){
    var date1 = $scope.work_start
    var date2 = $scope.work_end
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    $scope.daysBetween = diffDays
  }
});
```

Thanks to "[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)" for the getDaysBetween logic.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve the problem for now, but what I definitely need to do is something equal to what you suggest as angular typical markup. For my inputs in the html I have: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" ng-model="work_start"/>` and for the end: `<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="end" ng-model="work_end"/>` values are taken from here.

Comment: Glad to help, be sure to click the check if I answered your question. **Also**, if you're unaware, `Date` objects are a total pain in js - they have a steep learning curve. If you're doing a lot with dates/times check out  [Sugar](https://sugarjs.com/dates/) or [Moment](http://momentjs.com/). **Also**, it looks like [$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) is a listener, so when one of the values change, it runs the function. A fine way to do it, however, again, Dates can be a bitch.

Comment: **Thank you**, I'll be taking a look to those, (to Sugar and Moment), by the way, regarding to learning JS and Angular, I have a long journey on front. I will be posting more questions and doubts for sure!